# Should this answer (such style of answers) be deleted?

Tags: discussion, answers, deletion, deleted-answers

I've just [come across an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1169664) <sup>§</sup> to a question on Ramanujan summation, which seems to me to be simply a long suada of sentences - even although the verbal content is mathematics terminology. There is also no formatting whatsoever and for me a horror to read - and thus I think it is not helpful for the asker and also not helpful for the general MSE-reader. (It has also been downvoted two times). That answer is also older than 2 years and no attempt to improve that answer and make it more readable/understandable has been undertaken.

I've looked using google for some significant terms to make sure it is not just a copy&paste (and possibly automatic) from some other blog - but google didn't indicate such.

Next I was tempted to delete that answer, but hesitated, then thought to flag it for moderation - but the given categories do not really match (at least not "at the surface"). A moderator-intervention seemed to be an overkill, for me in that moment however (as moderators are human and their engagement is precious, should not be wasted for nothing).

*[added comment]* The problem, why I began hesitating, was that I could not easily recognize whether the text was possibly not only blabla - just unformatted, but then the answerer could have been asked to do that - but which, of course, I liked to assume. I didn't like to read more intensely into it to confirm this or that assumption about the quality of text: and I think this gives my question a  flair of also asking for similar other situations in more generality. *[/end added]*

> *Thus this question: How would you deal with such style of answers?*

<sup>§</sup> *The answer which I've linked to has now been deleted, so the link is automatically redirected to the question instead (which I didn't criticize) and the incriminated answer might no more be visible to readers with insufficient reputation. Sorry for that inconvenience!*

---

For the request of low-rep-user: here a screenshot of the deleted answer:
[image: picture]

Comment: The answer is absolutely terrible and should have been deleted years ago. It's unreadable, and if there is any mathematically worthwhile content in there I certainly cannot find it.

Comment: I agree that moderator intervention is overkill, as this is a matter ordinary users (with sufficiently many points) can handle on our own.

Comment: My word! I don't think you should even be asking this question. Just vote to delete, plain and simple!

Comment: By the way, what is a "suada", Gottfried?

Comment: @Gerry - a long sequence of accusing sentences, like a politician makes a very long and intense monologue against something (this is how I have met this term frequently)

Comment: Thanks to you and all those who voted to delete. Somehow it went unnoticed in CRUDE!

Comment: I think that the deletion itself made your link, originally to the answer, point to the question (which confused me, anyway!).  If this is correct, then it may not be a bad idea to indicate in the question text that this has happened.

Comment: @LSpice: thanks for notification. I edited my question.

Comment: What was it people? I have 78 rep and I'm missing out.

Comment: @LugGian : see my updated answer. I included a screenshot.

Comment: Thank you very much, I see where the controversy is.

Comment: In the OED "Suada" is marked as obsolete, and meaning "persuasiveness, persuasive eloquence" ... but that has not stopped certain on-line communities from using it in a new (opposite) sense.

Comment: @GEdgar : I remember his word as long as from my time in school in the 1970ies . Perhaps I got -a bit- used to it by my fathers use of words. At all - I don't use it regularly, it just came to my mind at the moment of writing. *(No on-line influence whatsoever... ;-) )*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It was terrible and I cast the final delete vote to delete it. Thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: Thanks, Zachary. Just for notifying I've appended to my question *why* I've begun hesitating ...

Comment: acceptet just to close the case now. Thanks, Zachary!